# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Indigo (version 3.7) for my Plug in development. I have created a plug-in and added Jersey archive jars in my Build Path . When i try to debug or run the application I am getting......

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
    at com.cts.adpart.testmanagement.jira.configwizard.JiraConnectionPage.connect(JiraConnectionPage.java:256)
    at com.cts.adpart.testmanagement.jira.configwizard.JiraConnectionPage.access$0(JiraConnectionPage.java:249)
    at com.cts.adpart.testmanagement.jira.configwizard.JiraConnectionPage$1.widgetSelected(JiraConnectionPage.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.cts.adpart.ui.configuration.pages.management.ManagementConfigurationBlock.showAddConfigurationWizard(ManagementConfigurationBlock.java:171)
    at com.cts.adpart.ui.configuration.pages.management.ManagementConfigurationBlock.access$1(ManagementConfigurationBlock.java:153)
    at com.cts.adpart.ui.configuration.pages.management.ManagementConfigurationBlock$2.linkActivated(ManagementConfigurationBlock.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleActivate(AbstractHyperlink.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.handleMouseUp(AbstractHyperlink.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink.access$2(AbstractHyperlink.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.AbstractHyperlink$4.handleEvent(AbstractHyperlink.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.cts.adpart.standalone.Application.start(Application.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client
    at com.cts.adpart.testmanagement.jira.api.JiraConnection.connect(JiraConnection.java:34)
    at com.cts.adpart.testmanagement.jira.configwizard.JiraConnectionPage$3$1.run(JiraConnectionPage.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 47 more



Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 51 more
```

Exception . I have no idea on how to resolve this issue. Any suggestion ?

Comment: what are jars included..???

Comment: I added the jersey archive jars.The issue is resolved , it was because i didnt include some sort of "." extension in the classPath in Runtime ... After i added it , it was resolved .

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `jersey-client.jar` file for the same

You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjerseyclientjar.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) .... The issue is resolved , it was because i didnt include some sort of "." extension in the classPath in Runtime ... After i added it , it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Or if you´re using maven write:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where version is the adecuate version.